# Best approach to implement multiple levels of difficulty to a minimax AI

Tags: algorithms, game-development, artificial-intelligence

I'm programming a game (turned base, in a grid) for which I implemented an AI using the minimax algorithm (with alpha-beta prunning). It's all fine and working, but the AI is too good and I can't win against it.

So now I want to introduce difficulties to the game (something like easy, normal and hard). The AI as it is right now would be the hard difficulty.

**My question : What is the best approach to implement multiple levels of difficulty to a minimax AI .**

I'm balancing between two ideas.

- going for different heuristics depending on the chosen difficulty
- adding some randomness to the choice of the best move. Let's say you choose Normal difficulty, then, x% of the times, I would choose the best move given by the same heuristic used for Hard.

Comment: I think you are heading in the right direction. You could also consider changing the depth you're looking ahead. This would also improve the performance for the "easier" ai's. - Maybe a combination of all three? Also try to test the different AI's early against human players, that will help a lot. Can't comment yet cause of reputation, so i post as answer.

Comment: Also useful would be changing how many levels of the game tree your minmax tries to search. But in general this is about how hard the AI "feels" to a human, rather than any objectively defined property of the algorithm, so there isn't necessarily an answer to this other than "find some volunteers to do AB testing on".

Comment: I've tackled this in two ways in the past:  Adjusting the depth of search and switching on/off parts of the evaluation.

Comment: "adding some randomness to the choice of the best move." - Actually this worked the best for me. I did it by randomly selecting the max search depth for each move. The higher the level - the most likely that hardest level depth will be chosen. Also near the end of the game I am reducing the chance of selecting smaller depths. This gives human like behavior, because as the games comes near the end - there are less available fields and less chance that real human would do something stupid. 
I didn't have much luck in introducing randomness to the evaluation function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many approaches you can try:

- weaken the evaluation function

  - break the eval up into two components: the first component is the standard score, the second component is a random value. Then you can use a `skill` parameter to weight how each component contributes to the final score
  - for games with different pieces, change randomly the value of the pieces (the perturbation is somewhat controlled via the `skill` parameter)
  - add a bounded random value for each root move (this is the ["Club Player" option](http://www.talkchess.com/forum/viewtopic.php?topic_view=threads&p=490440&t=45795) in Ed Schröder's Rebel Chess engine)
  - ...
- weaken the search algorithm

  - disable quiescence search / search extensions (i.e. check extension in chess)
  - prune random moves
  - reduce search depth /search speed
  - ...

The *artificial stupidity* topic is very well studied in chess (e.g. [Artificial stupidity - making a program play badly](http://www.talkchess.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=21264) or [Reducing Strength](http://www.talkchess.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=42880) for a lot of other interesting ideas).

For a real example you could take a look at Robert Hyatt's [Crafty engine](https://cis.uab.edu/hyatt/crafty/) and search for SKILL in the source.

Anyway you should consider that:

- there isn't a "best approach". You should try and mix different techiques and... results are very game-specific
- reducing playing strength against humans is quite easy, but making an engine to play in a fun, human-like way is very hard.